# Set two sinks with pulseaudio

Tags: audio, alsa, pulseaudio, shairplay, chromecast

I have two raop speakers that I can stream audio to from my Raspberry pi using Pulseaudio and [AirConnect](https://github.com/philippe44/AirConnect). At the moment, I can set either one as the default sink and it works as expected. I would like to be able stream the audio from the Raspberry pi to both of the speakers at the same time. Is it possible to set two default sinks in Pulseaudio or is it possible to create a third sink that somehow combines the two other sinks?

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to get it to work by combining the sinks

```
load-module module-combine-sink slaves=raop_output.raspberrypi.local,raop_output.raspberrypi.local.2

set-default-sink combined
```

This unfortunately leaves a slight delay between the two sinks, and also a strange crackle that doesn't happen when selecting either sink individually.